# Given truth values for boolean variables, x, y, and z, compute x XOR y XOR z

Tags: c++, xor

```
int main() {
  bool x,y,z;
  cin >> x >> y >> z;
  bool value = false; // change this line
  cout << x << " XOR " << y << " XOR " << z << " = " << value << endl;
}
```

Please help me fix "change this line."

Comment: Do you know what the XOR operator looks like in C++? It's easy to find. By the way what is the relation to fix-protocol?

Answer (score 1):

its simple

```
bool value = x^y^z;
```